# jQuery background-attachment in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Helping a friend working on the early beta of his site, I wrote a short jQuery snippet to keep a fixed background image from scrolling past the bottom edge of a div. Everything works perfectly in Firefox and Safari and even IE8, but Chrome (found on both Win7 and OSX 10.6) seems to have a problem once the background-attachment is changed from scroll back to fixed, where the image doesn't scroll with the page back up, and chunks of it get placed repeatedly on scrolling back down (hard to explain, check the demo link below). Is this something anyone else has encountered at all?

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imageHeight = 585;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($("div.main").height() + $("div.main").offset().top)) {
        $("div.main").css("background-position", "0px " + ($("div.main").height() - imageHeight) + "px");
    $("div.main").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
    }else{
        $("div.main").css("background-position", "right bottom");
        $("div.main").css("background-attachment", "fixed");
    }
});
```

});

Live demo:
http://mydigitalworld.dyndns.info/dns.html

Comment: Clarification, this is what happens in Chrome/Win7: http://grab.by/aop1

Comment: @David Yep, same happens on latest nightly Chromium.

Comment: @David, exactly what I'm seeing. Same in Mac and Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use background-repeat:no-repeat.

Having said that, I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve and why that couldn't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: We want to have the red gradient background image scroll with the page, unless it's past the end of its div, in which case the image will not pass the bottom edge of the div. I can't think of any way to do exactly that in purely CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately background-repeat makes no difference.